# Is there a way to simplify this code? Visual Basic Here

Tags: vb.net, simplify

I'm a newbie to Visual Basic and I have this code over here that's been bugging me. I can't think of another way to simplify this. Can you please help? Thanks!:

```
Private Sub PictureBox_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.Click,
PictureBox2.Click, PictureBox3.Click, PictureBox4.Click, PictureBox5.Click, PictureBox6.Click,
PictureBox7.Click, PictureBox8.Click, PictureBox9.Click, PictureBox10.Click, PictureBox11.Click,
PictureBox12.Click, PictureBox13.Click, PictureBox14.Click, PictureBox15.Click, PictureBox16.Click,
PictureBox17.Click, PictureBox18.Click, PictureBox19.Click, PictureBox20.Click, PictureBox21.Click,
PictureBox22.Click, PictureBox23.Click, PictureBox24.Click, PictureBox25.Click, PictureBox26.Click,
PictureBox27.Click, PictureBox28.Click, PictureBox29.Click, PictureBox30.Click, PictureBox31.Click,
PictureBox32.Click, PictureBox33.Click, PictureBox34.Click, PictureBox35.Click, PictureBox36.Click,
PictureBox37.Click, PictureBox38.Click, PictureBox39.Click, PictureBox40.Click, PictureBox41.Click,
PictureBox42.Click, PictureBox43.Click, PictureBox44.Click, PictureBox45.Click, PictureBox46.Click,
PictureBox47.Click, PictureBox48.Click, PictureBox49.Click, PictureBox50.Click, PictureBox51.Click,
PictureBox52.Click, PictureBox53.Click, PictureBox54.Click, PictureBox55.Click, PictureBox56.Click,
PictureBox57.Click, PictureBox58.Click, PictureBox59.Click, PictureBox60.Click, PictureBox61.Click,
PictureBox62.Click, PictureBox63.Click, PictureBox64.Click
        ...............
        ............... (stuff is down here.)
        ............... 
        ............... 

End Sub
```

Comment: Add those Controls to a `List(Of PictureBox)`, loop the collection and assign the same handler to all Controls in the collection. When the event is raised, the `sender` object is the Control that raised the event. Just cast it to PictureBox to access its properties.

Comment: I just learned how to dynamically make picture boxes. The problem is, however, I don't know how to dynamically assign the same handler to all the controls in the collection.

Comment: Use `AddHandler` on your dynamic controls, like David has shown in his answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to store the lists in a collection of some sort. This can either be an array or a List(Of PictureBox) or if all of the controls have the same parent you can simply leverage the Controls property.

Once you have the collection in place, you will need to iterate over collection and use AddHandler to reference. Inside the referenced method, you would get the sender, and convert it to a PictureBox.

Here is an example assuming all the PictureBox controls are on the Form:

```vb
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    For Each pb In Controls.OfType(Of PictureBox)()
        AddHandler pb.Click, AddressOf pb_Click
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub pb_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim pb = DirectCast(sender, PictureBox)
    ' pb is the control that was clicked
End Sub
```

Comment: This assumes all the PictureBoxes are directly contained by the Form.  It wouldn't work if the PictureBoxes were in different containers.

Comment: They are directly contained in the form. So thank you.

Comment: Wait a minute, how do I do
    For Each pb In Controls.OfType(Of PictureBox)()
        AddHandler pb.Click, AddressOf pb_Click
    Next

But for a List(Of Picturebox) named "Formula"?

Comment: @Idle_Mind - Correct. Just like I stated in the post.

Comment: @Darpmosh - Replace `Controls.OfType(Of PictureBox)` with `Formula`

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to build a list of the pictureboxes, with them "in order", assuming they are already on the form:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private PBs As New List(Of PictureBox)

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        For i As Integer = 1 To 64
            Dim ctlName As String = "PictureBox" & i
            Dim ctl As Control = Me.Controls.Find(ctlName, True).FirstOrDefault
            If Not IsNothing(ctl) AndAlso TypeOf ctl Is PictureBox Then
                Dim pb As PictureBox = DirectCast(ctl, PictureBox)
                AddHandler pb.Click, AddressOf PB_Click
                PBs.Add(pb)
            Else
                MessageBox.Show("Unable to find " & ctlName)
            End If
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub PB_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        Dim pb As PictureBox = DirectCast(sender, PictureBox)
        ' ... do something with pb ...
    End Sub

End Class
```

From the comments:

> Wait a minute, how do I do For Each pb In Controls.OfType(Of
> PictureBox)() AddHandler pb.Click, AddressOf pb_Click Next But for a
> List(Of Picturebox) named "Formula"?

```
For Each pb As PictureBox in Formula
    AddHandler pb.Click, AddressOf pb_Click
Next
```

Here's what you code produces after turning on the BorderStyle:

[image]

Comment: I want to Dynamically add a list of pictureboxes onto the form, and with my current code it doesn't work. Here's my code:
        For i = 0 To 3
            For j = 0 To 15
                Dim PB As New PictureBox
                PB.Name = "PictureBox" + ((j + 1) + i * 16).ToString
                PB.Location = New Point(20 + 37 * i, 52 + 43 * j)
                PB.Tag = i.ToString + Convert.ToByte(j).ToString
                PB.Size = New Point(37, 43)
                Me.Controls.Add(PB)
            Next
        Next

Comment: Just add the `AddHandler` call inside your loop: `AddHandler PB.Click, AddressOf NameOfMethodHere`

Comment: Huh? With my current loop, I somehow wasn't able to add ANY pictureboxes onto the form. that's a problem

Comment: Your code is adding the PictureBoxes, but you probably just can't see them!  Try setting the BackColor or BorderStyle property so you can see them.